# java: get download frequency from google play

Tags: java, google-play

If I have the url of the app in google play,
for example, I wnat to get the total number of download for the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=coconut.island.nk
are there any ways for me to get it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Final, I find http://developer.mevvy.com/
and it provide a simple method to get the apps data,
although there is a limited requests.